# Selenium 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute '_driver'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver (Firefox) with Python, I'm trying to press a log-in button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

actions = webdriver.ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/foryou?lang=ru')

login = driver.find_element_by_class_name('jsx-3665539393')
actions.click(login)

driver.close()
```

It opens Firefox, goes to Tiktok website and then I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING))
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Danil\PycharmProjects\untitled4\work.py", line 9, in <module>
    actions.click(login)
  File "C:\Users\Danil\Desktop\MF\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 103, in click
    if self._driver.w3c:
AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute '_driver'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm Ok with program not pressing the button, because I'm learning, but why I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 lines `actions = webdriver.ActionChains driver = webdriver.Firefox()` Should be changed to following.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
```

The `ActionChains` is not an attribute it is function.